# Swift generic type selection does not propagate

Tags: swift, generics, types

If I understand it correctly, Swift can determine the actual type of generics by different means, including matching by return type. The same (or a similar) mechanism is used for disambiguating overloaded functions. So this works as expected:

```
func getValue<T>()->T? {
    return nil
}

func getValue()->Int? {
    return 13
}

let b: Int? = getValue()
```

When running this, b will be `13`. Technically, both function signatures are a fit, but the latter is more specific to the requested return type.

Let's add a second function and tunnel the call through it:

```
func getGetValue<T>()->T? {
    return getValue()
}

let c: Int? = getGetValue()
```

When running this, c will be `nil`. In fact, the compiler will select the generic getValue() implementation to be called from getGetValue(), which is not what I want. IMHO, the requested return type should propagate through the second generic when choosing between the two implementations of getValue(), resulting in the same behavior as in the first example.

What am I missing? (Xcode 7.1)

Comment: Excellent find. My guess is that infer-by-return-type doesn't work when there's another layer of abstraction. Once inside `getGetValue`, the compiler has no idea that type `T` is, so the first function is the only one that matches.

Comment: @ZoffDino That would be my guess as well, but I do not understand why the compiler cannot propagate the types bottom-up. From my point, it looks like a bug - but I am not a compiler-guy. Maybe there is a perfectly valid reason for this behavior. I'll file a radar, just in case.

Comment: There's an entry in the Swift blog [Memory Safety: Ensuring Values are Defined Before Use](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=28) that discusses how far the compiler go to prove the correctness of the program. I think it's somewhat relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

You were just forgetting to cast.

```
func getValue<T>()->T? {
    return nil
}

func getValue()->Int? {
    return 13
}

let b: Int? = getValue() // 13

func getGetValue<T>()->T? {
    return getValue() as? T
}

let c: Int? = getGetValue() // 13
```